# Rails: Seeds, Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I want to push dummy content in my database. There is a 1:n relationship concepted in my models.

`seeds.rb`:

```
city= City.create([{:ort_name=>"Hagen"}])
person= Person.create([{:name = "root"}])
```

I try this

```
city << person
```

and

```
person.city_id = city.id
```

How would you do this?

Comment: maybe somebody knows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. It seems like you have a relationship where a city has many people. If so, then you can assign the relationship like this:

```
city.people << person
```

or this

```
person.city_id = city.id
person.save
```

This method requires `save` since assigning the `city_id` to `person` does not write the change to the database.

You can try these out in your `rails console`

Comment: i try both: I get undefinied method people or id